# jQuery no Fade on Page Load

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, fade

I've created your typical jQuery slider (code from [here](http://jqueryfordesigners.com/jquery-tabs/)). Everything works just fine as is, except I don't want the `fadeIn()` to run when the page loads (it just looks weird since the user hasn't clicked anything yet). Any ideas how to fix this? Basically I want to leave it as is, except no fade on page load. Thanks!

```
// Tab slides
$(function () {
    var tabContainers = $('div.slider > div');

    $('div.slider ul.slider-nav a').click(function () {
        tabContainers.hide().filter(this.hash).fadeIn();

        $('div.slider ul.slider-nav a').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');

        return false;
    }).filter(':first').click();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Tab slides
$(function () {
    var tabContainers = $('div.slider > div'),
        loaded = false;

    $('div.slider ul.slider-nav a').click(function () {
        var tab = tabContainers.hide().filter(this.hash);
        if (loaded){
          tab.fadeIn();
        }else{
          tab.show();
        }
        loaded = true;

        $('div.slider ul.slider-nav a').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');

        return false;
    }).filter(':first').click();
});
```

Explanation: The script is loading a click handler, then (once loaded) calling the click handler it just created. Because of this, it will fade (as the handler is instructing it to do). This can be avoided by added a check (in this cases the `loaded` variable) that basically lets the first click flow through without any intervention, but makes any future calls apply the fade.

Comment: It would probably be safer to have the loaded flag within a closure instead of out on the global scope.

Comment: @T.Stone: Indeed, fixing. Thanks.

Comment: This works, except nothing in the slider shows until you click on one of the nav links. I guess I wasn't descriptive enough, sorry. I still want the first image to show, just no `fadeIn()`

Comment: @ansarob: That was my mistake. I wasn't aware it was hidden to begin (or didn't think about it). Try the new revision that uses `show()` on the first call, and `fadeIn` on successive calls.

Answer (score 0):

You could set a flag after the first run, which is then checked on successive runs.

```
// Tab slides
$(function () {
    var tabContainers = $('div.slider > div');
    var firstRun = true;

    $('div.slider ul.slider-nav a').click(function () {
        tabContainers.hide().filter(this.hash);
        if(!firstRun) { tabContainers.fadeIn(); firstRun = false; }

        $('div.slider ul.slider-nav a').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');

        return false;
    }).filter(':first').click();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Well can't you just remove

```
tabContainers.hide().filter(this.hash).fadeIn();
```

?